# While macro bind_quoted breaks on first iteration

Tags: elixir

Maybe I am misunderstanding the use of bind_quoted but take this simple while loop macro:

```
defmodule Loop do
  defmacro while(expression, do: block) do
    quote bind_quoted: [expression: expression, block: block] do
      for _ <- Stream.cycle([:ok]) do
        if(expression) do
          block
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
Interactive Elixir (1.8.0) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help) 
iex(1)> c "loop.ex" 
[Loop] 
iex(2)> import Loop
iex(3)> while 1 == 1 do 
...(3)> IO.puts "hi"
...(3)> end
hi
```

I would expect an infinite loop of "hi" but instead only get one iteration. If I remove the bind_quoted and simple unquote() each argument, it works as expected.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use bind_quoted, it evaluates the pieces you pass in. So the `IO.puts "hi"` is evaluated in `[expression: expression, block: block]`, not inside your `if` block. You're just injecting an `:ok` there.

As an example, let's define some macros that do nothing except evaluate what's passed in:

```
defmodule AB do
  defmacro a(block) do
    quote bind_quoted: [block: block] do
      block
      block
      :ok
    end
  end

  defmacro b(block) do
    quote do
      unquote(block)
      unquote(block)
      :ok
    end
  end
end
```

Ignoring some warnings from the first one, let's call each of these with a block containing `IO.inspect/1` and see what happens:

```
iex> require AB
iex> AB.a(IO.inspect(1 + 1))
... (some warnings)
2
:ok
iex> AB.b(IO.inspect(1 + 1))
2
2
:ok
```

In macro `a/1`, the sum + inspect happens outside of the quoting, so it only gets called the once. In macro `b/1`, the sum + inspect happens anywhere we unquote `block`.